# In a Makefile: Given a set of source files, how to I create a static library instead of an executable?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile which currently builds an executable, and I am attempting to modify it to build a static library instead.

My 'all' currently looks like this:

```
all:
    gcc $(SRC_FILES) -o $(PRODUCT_NAME) $(LD_FLAG) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) $(INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS)
```

Where `SRC_FILES` is built by collecting all of the c files in several subdirectories:

```
SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/src/ -name '*.c')
SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/external_libs/jsmn -name '*.c')
SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
```

So I understand that in order to build a static library (`.a`), I will have to replace this with two steps:

1. create object files from each of the source files
2. create an archive (using the `ar` command)

My question is, what is the simplest way to do this?  The examples I have seen online, for example [this one](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/GCC/create-libraries/index) have a separate call to `gcc` for each object file.

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
gcc $(SRC_FILES) ...
(get object files somehow)
ar rvs libfoo.a $(OBJ_FILES)
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This is really a question about how to call the compiler correctly than how to do that from a `Makefile` in particular, and obviously depends on the platform as well as somewhat on the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build all source files into *object files*, and then add the object files to the archive.

For this I suggest you use the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) to build just about everything.

Then the makefile could be something like this:

```
OBJ_FILES = $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)

libfoo.a: $(OBJ_FILES)
    ar rcs libfoo.a $(OBJ_FILES)
```

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you!